# Static - non static interaction

Tags: java, oop, static

I have two Classes interacting with each other. The first one is a central one and is as follows:

```
public class Datenbank {
double winkelPanel = 0;
double groessePanel = 0;
double effizienzPanel = 0;
double maxProduktion = 0;
```

Here I initialize my variables and give them Values. Later down the same class, there is the function *addPanel*:

```
public void addPanel(double richtung, double winkel, double groesse, 
                                    double effizienz, double maxProd) {     
    groessePanel += groesse;                                                
    if (richtPanel == 0){ richtPanel += richtung/100; }                         
    else { richtPanel += richtung/100; richtPanel /= 2; }                        

    if (winkelPanel == 0){ winkelPanel = winkel; }
    else { winkelPanel += winkel; winkelPanel /= 2; }  

    if(effizienzPanel == 0) { effizienzPanel = effizienz/100; }
    else {effizienzPanel += effizienz/100; effizienzPanel /= 2; }

    if(maxProduktion == 0) { maxProduktion = maxProd; }
    else {maxProduktion += maxProd; maxProduktion /= 2;}
```

Which, by itself, is fine (from my knowledge). Now there is another Class, from a GUI that interacts with it.

```
if(menuItem == mPanelHinzufuegen) {
        double Flaeche = Double.parseDouble(showInput("Fläche des Panels in m^2:"));
        double Richtung = Double.parseDouble(showInput("Richtung des Panels(S = 0, W = 90, 0 = -90):"));
        double winkel = Double.parseDouble(showInput("Winkel des Panels in Grad, z.B. 23.5:"));
        double effizienz = Double.parseDouble(showInput("Effizienz des Panels, z.B. 23.5:"));
        double maxProd = Double.parseDouble(showInput("Max. Produktion des Panels in Watt:"));

        Datenbank.addPanel(Richtung, winkel, Flaeche, effizienz, maxProd);

    }
```

When I get to the point of invoking Datenbank.addPanel, I get a compiler error because the GUI one is static but the Datenbank one is not. Simply adding "static" to the *addPanel* method doesn't work, as the variables (winkelPanel etc.) start throwing out an error that those are non static and therefore cannot be used like that.

Comment: exactly what error are you phasing while making addPanel to satic ?

Comment: The variables in `Database` will also need to be static.

Comment: you cannot access non static member from static method

Comment: Based on your code you either need to make `addPanel` and the fields in `DataBank` static (not really recommended). Or you just make a DataBank instance: `DataBank db = new DataBank();` and then use that like so: `db.addPanel(...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why make it static at all?

```
Datenbank db = new Datenbank();
db.addPanel(Richtung, winkel, Flaeche, effizienz, maxProd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based from your setup I assume that `Datenbank` (database in English) is a singleton and therefore should only be instantiated once in your application.

Therefore you can rewrite that class as a singleton:

```
public enum Datenbank {
  INSTANCE;
  double winkelPanel = 0;
  double groessePanel = 0;
  double effizienzPanel = 0;
  double maxProduktion = 0;
  public void addPanel(double richtung, double winkel, double groesse, 
                                double effizienz, double maxProd) {
  ...
}
```

This example assumes that your class `Datenbank` has a default constructor, otherwise you would have to provide the appropriate arguments to `INSTANCE`.

Then you can access that instance in your GUI:

```
Datenbank.INSTANCE.addPanel(Richtung, winkel, Flaeche, effizienz, maxProd);
```

Answer (score 0):

adding the 'static' keyword to addPanel will not be sufficient. You need to make all the instance variable of the 'Datenbank' class as static

```
public class Datenbank {
static double winkelPanel = 0;
static double groessePanel = 0;
static double effizienzPanel = 0;
static double maxProduktion = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables in Datenbank doesn't make sense in a static context unless they where static, which would mean that you have just one of them for the class. They should be static if you are using them in a static method.
Whether you create an object of type Datenbank to invoke addPanel, whether you declare the class variables as static (makes less sense in this context to me).
Declare the variables as private as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the "static"-method of Datenbank which doesn't exist.

Your want to add a panel to a specific instance of Datenbank, means an Datenbank-object which was instanciated by "new".

So your GUI-Class has to have a member or a method which provides a database-object and then you can call the addPanel.

The main issue here is: static is for classes, and the non-static part is for instances.